# DataContext binding doesn't update after property change

Tags: wpf, binding, datacontext

I have many cell that can be updated via keyboard or via backend. During update via backend the first one work, the second no. Why?
In the second one I have tried to simplify binding forcing the datacontext.

```
  <UI:ReadWriteCell Grid.Column="22" Grid.Row="0"
                      IsReadOnly="{Binding ElementName=OreProduzioneViewCtl,Path=Giorno.H23.Data,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Converter={StaticResource GiornoPassato}}"
                      Text="{Binding ElementName=OreProduzioneViewCtl,Path=Giorno.H23.PotenzaModificabile,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus,Converter={StaticResource PotenzaModificabile}}"/>
    <UI:ReadWriteCell Grid.Column="23" Grid.Row="0"  DataContext="{Binding ElementName=OreProduzioneViewCtl,Path=Giorno.H24,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                      IsReadOnly="{Binding Path=Data,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Converter={StaticResource GiornoPassato}}"
                      Text="{Binding Path=PotenzaModificabile,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus,Converter={StaticResource PotenzaModificabile}}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

MSDN says  "FrameworkElement.DataContext Property" is for

Gets or sets the data context for an element when it participates in data binding.

and

XAML Values

dataContextObject

A directly embedded object that serves as data context for any bindings within the parent element. Typically, this object is a Binding or another BindingBase derived class. Alternatively, raw data of any CLR object type intended for binding may be placed here, with the actual bindings defined later.

bindingUsage

A binding usage that evaluates to an appropriate data context

resourceExtension

One of the following: StaticResource or DynamicResource. This usage is used when referring to raw data defined as an object in resources.

contextResourceKey

The key identifier for the object being requested from within a ResourceDictionary.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.datacontext(v=vs.110).aspx